# JQuery: How to strip sub-elements from a div and generate a new HTML without use of intermediate element to load

Tags: jquery

I have a div with id 'id1' which has content such as:

```
 <div id="id1">
    abcd pqr
    <div class="cl1">...</div>
    <div class="cl2">...</div>
 </div>
```

I want an HTML string which is

```
'<div id="id1"> abcd pqr </div>'
```

I do not want to use an intermediate div to load the HTML and then remove elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone it , remove children from clone, trim the final text and get the outerHTML of the manipulated clone

```js
const $el = $('#id1').clone()
$el.children().remove().end().text((_, txt) => txt.trim())

console.log($el[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">
    abcd pqr
    <div class="cl1">...</div>
    <div class="cl2">...</div>
 </div>
```